# Different reconstruction errors using different PCA algorithms

Tags: pca, error

In Matlab, I perform PCA on a centered and scaled (std-scaled) data set `X_cs` in four ways:

1. **`builtin pca`** using the builtin [`pca` function](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) with default `svd` algorithm
2. **`cov-eig`** computing the covariance matrix of `X_cs` and then doing the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix
3. **`cov-svd`** computing the covariance matrix of `X_cs` and then doing the SVD of the covariance matrix
4. **`svd`** doing the SVD of the `X_cs'`

Finally, I also do PCA in Python:

5. **`python`** using the [`PCA` function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) from `sklearn.decomposition`

I then reconstruct the data using all found PCs, uncenter and unscale it. Let the reconstructed data be called `X_app`, for each of the four ways I compute the RMS error and also the normalized (by mean) RMS error. There is a discrepancy in the errors between all five methods and I wonder what could be the source of that.

Specifically, the default builtin `pca` function should use the `svd` agorithm: `Default. Singular value decomposition (SVD) of X.` So why is it different from the SVD done 'by hand'? Another interesting thing that I check is when I change the `'Algorithm'` of the Matlab builtin `pca` function to `'eig'` it also does not correspond to the errors obtained from 2. (however, the errors in that case are the lowest).

Why do different PCA algorithms result in different reconstruction errors?

[image]

[image]

In order to also judge where the differences are, as suggested by the comment of **ttnphns**, I checked the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for different algorithms. The distribution of the eigenvalues look pretty similar for `builtin pca`, `cov-eig` and `cov-svd`, however the values are not exactly the same. For instance, the first eigenvalues of `builtin pca` start to differ at at a second decimal place compared to `cov-eig` or `cov-svd`. On the other hand, the eigenvalues of `cov-eig` vs. `cov-svd` differ at a much further decimal place, for instance the second eigenvalue at 13th place.

[image]

Similar thing can be seen for the eigenvectors. When plotted, the weights on eigenvectors look pretty much the same for three algorithms: `builtin pca`, `cov-svd` and `svd` (**instead of `cov-eig`, like was the case for the eigenvalues**). Typically, the differences can be seen starting from the 14th decimal point.

[image]

Taking into account the comment of **ttnphns**, another question is: should I even bother to investigate this? One motivation to investigate those differences might be to find out if certain algorithm is simply finding a *better* basis from the quality of reconstruction point of view. I look forward to your suggestions.

Code:

1.

```matlab
[A_builtin, Z_builtin, eig_builtin] = pca(X_cs, 'Centered', false, 'economy', false);
X_tilde_builtin = Z_builtin * A_builtin';
```

2.

```matlab
C = cov(X_cs);
[A_cov_eig, eig_cov_eig] = eig(C);
eig_cov_eig = sort(diag(eig_cov_eig), 'descend');
Z_cov_eig = X_cs * A_cov_eig;
X_tilde_cov_eig = Z_cov_eig * A_cov_eig';
```

3.

```matlab
C = cov(X_cs);
[U, S, ~] = svd(C);
A_cov_svd = U;
eig_cov_svd = diag(S);
Z_cov_svd = X_cs * A_cov_svd;
X_tilde_cov_svd = Z_cov_svd * A_cov_svd';
```

4.

```matlab
[U, S, V] = svd(X_cs');
A_svd = U;
eig_svd = diag(S);
Z_svd = X_cs * A_svd;
X_tilde_svd = Z_svd * A_svd';
```

5.

```
pca = PCA()
pca.fit(X_cs)
scores = pca.transform(X_cs)
PCs = pca.components_
eigvals = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
X_tilde_python = np.dot(scores, PCs)
```

Comment: My advice will be to track where the differences _begin_. Second point, if are bothered with discrepancies after, say, 10th decimal digit - then you better shouldn't: different packages may use not exactly same linear algebra algorithms or same implementations of those.

Comment: Your first graphic looks like pure noise from accumulated floating point imprecision.  I wouldn't be surprised to see errors of that size arise from trivial changes such as reordering the variables in the PCA, either.  Consequently, I saw little point in exploring the remaining graphics.

Comment: @whuber, thanks a lot for your comment. Indeed, I still wonder if I should even care about it or not :) I don't reorder the variables, all PCAs were done on exactly the same dataset. Do you have knowledge of where the differences in eigenvectors and eigenvalues (I'm talking about the substantial ones) can come from? I don't know the linear algebra of this, but is it possible that say `cov-eig` eigenvector is a rotation of an eigenvector from a different algorithm?

Comment: My point is that even trivial changes in the input can create these kinds of changes in the output: that gives you a threshold for determining what differences are worth paying attention to.  If there are more substantial differences in output, that's almost surely because of different normalization conventions.  That makes it important to study the documentation closely.